# PHP - Cast type from variable

Tags: php, casting

I was asking myself if it's possible to cast a string to become another type defined before

e.g.

```
$type = "int";
$foo = "5";
$bar = ($type) $foo;
```

and where $bar === 5

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there's a built-in function for that:

```
$type = "int";
$foo = "5";
settype($foo, $type); // $foo is now the int 5
```

Note that the return value of `settype()` is the success state of the operation, and not the converted variable. Thanks to @NRVM below.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Comment: Yet you can turn a `string` into a `boolean`, so this approach is not very clean... Still looking for a way to do it with a correct error returned if casting really fails.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the above comment, [setting a variable will not return the number but a boolean for the succes state](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php#81595).

```
<?php
$type = "int";
$foo = "5";
$bar = settype($foo, $type);
var_dump($foo);
// bool(true) 
// $bar = 1

settype($foo, $type);
var_dump($foo);
// int(5)
```